# How could I replicate this Log-log plot for a Pareto Distribution in r?

Tags: r, plot, statistics

I'm trying to replicate this plot

[image]

which, according to the article, the full line has been plotted generating random numbers with this equation

[image]

The code that I used to generate the random numbers is

```
r <- c(runif(600, min = 0, max = 1))
pnumbers = c()
a = 0.17
b = 4200
for(i in 1:600){
  pnumbers[i] = a*(1 - r[i]*(1 - (a/b)^0.75))^(-1/0.75)
}
x2 <- sort(pnumbers)
```

and using that random numbers in the equation 11 showed in this picture

[image]

That function was calculated with this code

```
pareto1 <- ppareto(x2, 0.17, 0.75)
survpareto <- 1 - pareto1
```

I could get the straight dotted line but I have not been able to get the curve graph with the empty circles.  It is suposed that the empty cicles plot was made of the data set and the equation 11, but I got another straight line! Actually... the same straight line!!
[The graph that I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGLN9.png)
That plot I got it with this code

```
pdf("PruebaGraficoLogLog.pdf")
pareto2 <- 1 - (0.17/x)^0.75
survpareto2 <- 1 - pareto2
plot(x2, survpareto, log = "xy", col = "blue", type = "l", lty = 5)
points(x, survpareto2, log = "xy")
dev.off()
```

My question is, what do I have to do in order to replicate the firt plor correctly? What am I doing wrong?
Thanks for your help and cooperation.

**EDIT:** I changed the title in order to make it more specific and detailed.
This is the preamble (packages) that I used in my toy model

```
library(EnvStats)
library(stats)
library(base)
```

I have not used the package `fitdistrplus` because (and I don't know why) I haven't could install it in my computer. I'm using R 3.3 but the installation of the package always fails.

Comment: There are a few details missing from your post. From which library did you take `ppareto`? Randomly generated data will only be reproducible if you used a fixed random seed (which you haven't). The solid line from the figure corresponds to a truncated Pareto distribution. `VGAM` has functions pertaining to the truncated Pareto distribution. Have you already had a look at `VGAM`? The parameters you give do not match the survival distribution shown by the circles in the figure (see my answer below). How did you arrive at those values?

Answer (score 2):

**Two important comments first:**

- The survival distribution of your samples shown by the circles in the figure do *not* match parameters `a`, `b`, `c` that you give in your post. Can you please explain how you arrived at these particular values: `a = 0.17`, `b = 4200`, `c = 0.75`?
- I have to say that I don't quite understand the whole point of the exercise. The figure shows samples from a bounded/truncated Pareto distribution (drawn using inverse-transform sampling, see below); it is then shown that the survival distribution of the samples agrees with that of a bounded Pareto distribution, rather than an unbounded Pareto distribution (which obviously is as expected). This is usually something you do when you are trying to *estimate* parameters from an underlying distribution (here: bounded Pareto). **So are you perhaps asking how to *estimate* parameters of the truncated Pareto distribution?** If so, this will depend on the data (**in the case of random data, no fixed seed means no reproducibility**) and the estimation method (usually ML). Perhaps taking a look at `MASS:fitdistr` will be useful.

---

These comments aside, here is a reproducible example to generate `x` and plot `log x` vs. `log S(x)`.

1. Generate `n=600` samples `x` according to the equation you give (I assume that's Eq. 13 from the figure caption).

   ```
   set.seed(2018)
   rsample <- function(n, a, b, c) a * (1 - runif(n) * (1 - (a / b)^c)) ^ (-1 / c)

   x <- rsample(600, 0.17, 4200, 0.75)
   ```

   Note that `x` are generated through [inverse-transform sampling (ITS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_transform_sampling) from a [bounded Pareto distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_distribution#Bounded_Pareto_distribution). It's easy to map coefficients `a`, `b`, `c` to those from the definition of the bounded Pareto distribution from Wikipedia:

   ```
   a = L         (location parameter)
   b = H         (location parameter)
   c = alpha     (shape parameter)
   ```
2. We calculate the empirical cumulative distribution function `F_X(x) = P(X ≤ x)` using `ecdf`

   ```
   Px <- ecdf(x)
   ```
3. We can now calculate `F_X(x)` for any values `x` (keeping in mind that the support of a bounded Pareto distribution is `L ≤ x ≤ H`). We choose values such that they correspond to the interval shown on a log-scale in the figure. The survival function is then simply `S_X(x) = 1 - F_X(x) = P(X > x)`.

   ```
   library(tidyverse)
   df <- data.frame(
       x = exp(seq(0, 1.6, 0.05))) %>%
       mutate(
           Px = Px(x),
           Sx = 1 - Px)
   ```
4. We plot `x` vs. the survival function `S_X(x)` on a log-log-scale.

   ```
   ggplot(df, aes(log(x), log(Sx))) +
       geom_point(size = 3, shape = 21)
   ```

[image]

**As you can see, the shape of the survival distribution does not match that of the figure, demonstrating that parameters `a = 0.17`, `b = 4200`, `c = 0.75` do not agree with the parameters used for the survival function samples from the figure.**

Comment: Hi, Maurits.  Thanks for your answer.  I have to clarify something: when I said that I want to reproduce the graph I wasn't meaning that I wanted to replicate THAT graph.  I' meaning that want to replicate te **TYPE** of graph (with any values of a, b and c parameters).  If I plot the survival Pareto function with the chosen values of a, b and c parameters I get the right line, but when I plot the data x vs the survival pareto function I get the same sight line. What I want to know is what do I have to plot, using my data, in order to get the curve line made of empty circles.

Comment: In my research I get 600 real data with a min value 0.17 and a max value 4200.  So, in my question I tried to use a toy model in order to know hoy to plot the empty circles curve.

Comment: @Fabio You can plot an empirical survival function exactly as I demonstrate in my answer. The shape depends on the parameters. Adjust e.g. `c` to affect the “degree” of the “bend”. Did you actually take a look at the example I give? Is something not clear?

Comment: @Fabio Can you also please edit your original question to "tidy up" your post. Add critical clarifications in the main post, and give it a more descriptive title. This seems to be about how to plot a survival function for a specific distribution (here truncated Pareto). Lastly a piece of general advice: It is expected from you that you "hang around" to respond to comments in a timely way. Posting a question and then not responding for days is not considered very courteous and polite behaviour around here. We are all happy to help but we expect you to be an active and responsive SO member.

Comment: I apologyze because I answerso late your comments and sugestions. It is because, in this moment of my life, I have to do a lor of things because of my masters degrees studies.  I have not tried your suggestion but I'm going to do it and then I'll tell you it was it.